# Graph a ParameterMixtureDistribution

Tags: plotting, graphics, probability-or-statistics, distributions, histograms

I am trying to graph the following 'ParameterMixtureDistribution'.

```
pmd = ParameterMixtureDistribution[
  GammaDistribution[m/v, m^2/
   v], {m \[Distributed] 
    UniformDistribution[{0.00000001, 0.2}], 
   v \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{0.00000001, 0.2}]}]
```

I would know if `PDF[pmd]` were to return something but it does not. Is there a way I can graph my complex distribution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you should report this to support. I'm not sure if this can be classified as a bug, but this takes way longer than it's supposed to, even after replacing the inexact `0.00000001` and `0.2` with the equivalents `1*^-8` and `1/5`.

In the meantime, here is a very hack-y method for (relatively quickly) evaluating the PDF of your distribution:

```
pmd = ParameterMixtureDistribution[GammaDistribution[m/v, m^2/v],
                                   {m \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{1*^-8, 1/5}], 
                                    v \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{1*^-8, 1/5}]}];

Block[{Integrate = NIntegrate}, PDF[pmd, 3.]] // AbsoluteTiming
   {0.254763, 0.0171523}
```

Compare this with

```
PDF[pmd, 3.] // AbsoluteTiming
   {114.855, 0.0171523}
```

As for your plot:

```
Plot[Block[{Integrate = NIntegrate}, PDF[pmd, x]], {x, 0, 5}]
```

[image: plot of ParameterMixtureDistribution PDF]

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the values of m and v.

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[PDF[pmd /. {m -> m0, v -> v0}, x], {x, 0, 0.2}], {{v0, 2}, 1, 
  5}, {{m0, 1}, 1, 4}]
```

[image]